# How to add 2 hyperlinks in a single cell in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, hyperlink

I have an excel file that contains a list of steps that I follow at work.

I want to add hyperlinks to the emails I have received & saved on the hard drive.

Every time I try to add a hyperlink to text in Excel 2010, the entire cell points to it.

Is there a way to add 2 separate hyperlinks to text within a single cell in Excel 2010?

[image]

In the above image, instead of creating 2 cells linking to the emails, I want to add the links to the text itself (& eliminate the additional columns for emails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel 2010 only allows you to create **one** hyperlink per cell. A workaround is to add a *Microsoft Word Object* with two or more hyperlinks in it: go to *Insert* > *Object* > *Microsoft Word Document*

[image: MS Word Object in Excel]

Comment: Ctrl + F doesn't search within the text in Word Object. Say I have a 100 links - to enter it manually & being unable to search... Defeats the purpose of having a quick referance manual.. Is there another way?

Comment: Yes I know, It has some disadvantages. Maybe you could try to create a script that extracts the links, and then puts them in separate cells.